# Make a popup (not modal) browser window stay visible even when not active

Tags: javascript, popup

Is there anyway to make a popup window (not a modal) stay visible, even when it is inactive. I know this sounds like a ridiculous question, and I'm expecting that this can't be done.

But if it can be, any direction will be much appreciated. I found the "dependent" property, which is not supposed to work on OSX - which I am using.

http://www.gtalbot.org/BugzillaSection/Bug195867GDR_WindowOpen.html#GrpFunctionalityFeatures

I don't need this to be cross browser/OS compatible, if it works on a single platform/browser then that's ok.

I'm not sure if "dependent" will do the trick or there's another/better way.

Comment: By "stay visible" do you mean: "stay on top" even if user changes focus to the original window, or just kept open and visibility would be managed by the OS, like any other window?

Comment: You can't do it with Javascript and probably "you shouldn't". The best thing you can do is install some application in the OS of the users that makes the window to stay on top. But, that is just as ridiculous as the requirement.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722681/how-do-i-force-a-browser-window-to-always-be-on-top-and-in-focus

Comment: @Floremin - the first one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can control "always on top" behaviour of the browser window using JavaScript from the browser. However, if the popup is always on top, then it must be blocking a part of your browser window. So, instead of a new browser window, make it a `<div>` block with `position: fixed;` and place it where you want on the page. This you can control with JavaScript.